# When I create a list of random characters in random order, how can I save that list to further work with that randomized list of characters

Tags: python

This is what I have.

```
import random
list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']


for i in range(400):
    k = random.randint(0, 25)
    print(list[k], end='')
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print('')`
```

now I wanna take this randomized 400 characters and just print the first 200 in a different list

Answer (score 1):

This would do it. You would add each number that you generate to a new list. You then access the first 200 items in the list using slice notation, and print it out.

```
import random
list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n'
    ,'o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
new_list = []

for i in range(400):
    k = random.randint(0, 25)
    print(list[k], end='')
    new_list.append(list[k])
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print('')

print(new_list[:200])
```

I will add, however, that generating 400 random letters, and printing 100 per line across 4 lines (which seems to be what your complex for loop is doing), would be achieved faster and more idiomatically using the following:

```
import random
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n'
    ,'o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
random_400 = random.choices(letters, k=400)
for i in range(len(letters)/100+1):
    print " ".join(letters[i*100:(i+1)*100]) + "\n"
```